# Expression evaluate in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, dll, expression

I have table name expression table like this 
id  expression

```
1   a+b
2   SQRT(a)*c
3   a/b+3
4   a*a
```

also another table named dataentry like

```
time a b c 
9.15 2 5 0
9.30 1 0 7
```

So now I want to evaluate the expression from expression table and variables for expression from dataentry table ,also note that i have some special function which are store in a dll which can I also use .

If somebody suggest evalute this in mysql stored procedure but my limitation is some special function which are refrenced in dll ,so only have to evalute in c#.

Comment: You will have to give us something that you have tried? Do you have an application layer (e.g. in Java)? It would be a more appropriate place to perform such evaluations? What kind of dll do you have? CLR assembly or something else?

Comment: actually it s a vba converted to dll ,such function library where passing parameters to function and return results.

Comment: Do you have a front-end application that consumes data from MySql?

Comment: after completion of calculation part result table i can consume by devexpress tool in my web for front end ,but calculation engine type of thing first i have to make.....

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create `System.Linq.Expressions` from it, but since the format you specified is not neccessarily in a "native" expressions format plus you mentioned you have methods referenced in external libraries, an easier approach might be to use Roslyn and generate/run that code on the fly (see http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compilation/CSharpCompilation.cs for details or search SO for it). The advantage of this approach would be that you can use most of your expressions as they are without the need of converting them.

```
using static System.Math;
var a = 2; // taken from db dataentry table
var c = 7; // taken from db dataentry table

// statement taken from db expression table
// Sqrt(a)*c
var result = Sqrt(a)*c;
```

The benefit here is, that your expression are not bound to C# language (even if your main code that compiles them is C#).

In case you still want to create LINQ expressions you could do so by creating your expression like this:

```
using static System.Math;
var a = 2; // taken from db dataentry table
var c = 7; // taken from db dataentry table

// statement taken from db expression table
// Sqrt(a)*c
Expression<Func<double, double, double>> expression = (a, c) => Sqrt(a)*c;
var result = expression.Compile().Invoke(a, c);
```

Note: the latter only works if you have simpler statements whereas with the former you could evaluate more complex logic with branching etc.

If this is not what you actually wanted to know, could you please rephrase your question and provide more details?